# HtmlUnit Dependency Error - NoClassDefFoundException

Tags: java, http, maven-2, pom.xml, http-unit

recently I've been trying to use the HtmlUnit API, but for some reason, I'm unable to have all the dependencies I need. The first thing I did was go on the HtmlUnit site and search for a full list of the dependencies(http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html). I then searched the maven dependency for each of them until I had created the final pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>it.auties</groupId>
<artifactId>it.auties</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vault-repo</id>
        <url>http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>wesjd-repo</id>
        <url>https://nexus.wesjd.net/repository/thirdparty/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.milkbowl.vault</groupId>
        <artifactId>VaultAPI</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.wesjd</groupId>
        <artifactId>anvilgui</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-core-js</artifactId>
        <version>2.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-cssparser</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>neko-htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.12.v20180830</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I started my server, but when the plugin is loaded(I'm developing a spigotMC.org plugin), I get a NoClassDefFoundException:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace all those dependencies with only this one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
  <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version> <!-- use version that is suitable for you -->
</dependency>
```

If you need to use HtmlUnit just add it as dependency to your project Mavne will download all transitive dependencies itself.
Here is a link for Maven repo fro HtmlUnit:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit/2.4

Comment: I had already tried that, but at the end by using an older version I got it working(just like you did)